# тестирование apk с реальным cpu и gpu

Tags: android, cpu, resources, gpu

Добрый день. Есть ли возможность тестировать приложения на реальных аппаратах, но удаленно ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я пользовался https://appthwack.com/, мне понравилось. Гугл еще подсказывает http://testdroid.com/products. Полагаю, есть и другие.

Comment: благодарюв. То что надо !